# Django not able to authenticate username and password, although data is present is db and the entered data is checked correctly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**view.py**

```
def loginverify(request):
    print("-----------login verification------------")
    if request.method == "POST":
        cemail = request.POST.get("cemail")
        cpassword = request.POST.get('cpassword')
        print(cemail, cpassword) (able to print the data sent )

        User = authenticate(request, email=cemail, password=cpassword)
        print(User)-->(this shows none)
        if User is not None:
            login(request, User)
            print("no problem")
            messages.success(request, 'Login successful')
            return redirect('dashboard')  # Redirect to the user's dashboard or landing page
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid email or password')
            print("problem occurred")

            template = 'polls/login.html'
            return render(request, template)  # Redirect to login page

    template = 'polls/CustLandingpage.html'
    return render(request, template)
```

the data is received by this function but the authentication is not working

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  Email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    

        
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

for authentication email and password is used. I tried most of the things but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your Customer model doesn't extend any of the models provided by the authentication framework.

Therefore,

```
class Customer(AbstractUser):
```

Set Customer in your settings.py

Use the EmailField and Username Field:

```
class Customer(AbstractUser):
# If you don't want to use the built-in username field, 
set it to None or use the 'email' field
username = None
email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)  

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  # Use email 
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Use makemigrations and migrate

Let me know how you get on, good luck!

Comment: in my github I have a project named price comparison, teabag_lovers. This uses the authentication system in django. It has a specific app for it as part of the project. Take a look at the models / views and see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77915690/16508358), you can update the models.py file to this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class Customer(AbstractUser):
  # You can set the username to field None or set it to the value of the Email field
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  Email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    

        
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
```

and remember to set the Customer model as an auth user model in the setting.py.

Add the below line to it:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<your_app_name>.Customer'
```